# Is there a scala identity function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-option

If I have something like a `List[Option[A]]` and I want to convert this into a `List[A]`, the standard way is to use `flatMap`:

```
scala> val l = List(Some("Hello"), None, Some("World"))
l: List[Option[java.lang.String]] = List(Some(Hello), None, Some(World))

scala> l.flatMap( o => o)
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(Hello, World)
```

Now `o => o` is just an identity function. I would have thought there'd be some way to do:

```
l.flatMap(Identity) //return a List[String]
```

However, I can't get this to work as you can't generify an `object`. I tried a few things to no avail; has anyone got something like this to work?

Comment: I'd think that `{_}` should equate to `{x => x}` just as `{_ + 3}` equates to `{x => x+3}`.  Can anyone comment on why it is not so?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There's an identity [function in Predef](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/Predef$.html).

```
l flatMap identity[Option[String]]

> List[String] = List(Hello, World)
```

A for expresion is nicer, I suppose:

```
for(x <- l; y <- x) yield y
```

**Edit:**

I tried to figure out why the the type parameter (Option[String]) is needed. The problem seems to be the type conversion from Option[T] to Iterable[T].

If you define the identity function as:

```
l.flatMap( x => Option.option2Iterable(identity(x)))
```

the type parameter can be omitted.

Comment: How come the type inferencer can't figure out the types itself? Why doesn't `l.flatMap(identity): List[String]` work?

Comment: I thought that the inferencer could figure that out. I have no idea. I'll add a question. :-)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - See edit. It is related to implicit type conversions.

Comment: @Thomas - thanks. A shame about the identity/Option/Iterable thing as it seems like this is one of the primary places where it's likely to be used. Unfortunately it's less readable with identity than without

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work in scala 2.9.1. `l flatMap identity[Option[String]]
<console>:9: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Option[String] => Option[String]
 required: Option[java.lang.String] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
              l flatMap identity[Option[String]]
                                ^`

Answer (score 24):

FWIW, on Scala 2.8 you just call `flatten` on it. [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149311/thomas-jung) has it mostly covered for Scala 2.7. He only missed one alternative way of using that identity:

```
l.flatMap[String](identity)
```

It won't work with operator notation, however (it seems operator notation does not accept type parameters, which is good to know).

You can *also* call `flatten` on Scala 2.7 (on a `List`, at least), but it won't be able to do anything without a type. However, this works:

```
l.flatten[String]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just give the type inferencer a little help:

```
scala> val l = List(Some("Hello"), None, Some("World"))
l: List[Option[java.lang.String]] = List(Some(Hello), None, Some(World))

scala> l.flatten[String]
res0: List[String] = List(Hello, World)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala 3:

```
List(1,2,3).map(identity)

// val res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```