# Scala: default value for function parameter in higher order function

Tags: scala, default-value, higher-order-functions

I have higher order function:

```
def calculateFusionRiskContract(postCalc: DataFrame => DataFrame)
```

How i can set default value for postCalc parameter that just return parameter of postCalc? without any calculation?

```
def calculateFusionRiskContract(postCalc: DataFrame => DataFrame = ???)
```

Comment: `def calculateFusionRiskContract(postCalc: DataFrame => DataFrame = df => df)` - it wouldn't hurt to learn the language, lambdas are a very basic concept.

Answer (score 6):

The function that "just returns the parameter" is `identity`

```
def calculateFusionRiskContract(postCalc: DataFrame => DataFrame = identity) = ???
```

[Is there a scala identity function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797502/is-there-a-scala-identity-function)